# How to authenticate a nextjs api method using a jwt token and auth0

Tags: authentication, jwt, next.js, auth0

I’ve created an app with server side pages and an api using nextjs and have just been looking to integrate an authentication provider.

I’ve ran through some of the auth0 tutorials and have successfully created the authentication flow for the server side pages, but cannot clearly see how to authenticate the api. I can see how to do it with a session auth using the withApiAuthRequired function, but would like to authenticate my API’s using a jwt token, so they can be called independently of the website log-in (i.e. using an athorization code flow).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Auth0 - use their [React authentication library](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react). It provides an auth context, auth hook, and about everything required for Auth0 on the frontend.

Comment: I cant see any exmaples of protecting an api though (I could be missing it)